# Extracting NER from a Spanish language text file

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

I am trying to extract various Named Entities from a Spanish language text file. I tried using nltk but to no success. I am using Python 2 with nltk 3.x.

Comment: Another option is Stanford CoreNLP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the Python library [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) it has a model for [spanish language](https://spacy.io/models/es) that includes NER.

Comment: @VivekKhetan could you mark my answer as accepted